# foxpro cursor size

Tags: foxpro, database-cursor

This seems like such an easy problem, but I can't seem to find a solution anywhere.  My co-worker and I are working on an application that makes use of the Foxpro xml dump facilities.  It works great, but we're wishing to split the table into multiple files based on some size constraints.

This seems like it should be the easy part:  How do you find the size of a cursor in Foxpro?

Comment: can you get me a copy of the structure and some sample values... even if you have to fudge the data? (drapp@dvrss.com) and how do you want to split.. .what is the basis of the split a 2 gig file limit?  Are you using CursorToXML(), or XMLAdapter class.

Comment: The structure is unknown, that's kindof the point of the question.

The app is passed the name of a cursor and it will chose to split it based on a constraint, which is also passed in as an argument.  It has nothing to do with the 2gig file limit and more to do with memory in the application receiving the XML.

Initially we were going to split on rows, but it occurred to us that we had no idea how to check the size of memofields (if applicable).

Comment: This will be done in VFP... Correct??? which Version if so...

Comment: Didn't know if you checked my latest post from last week with a full function to dump as I THINK you want the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean file size, you can find the file a cursor relates to by calling the DBF() function with the cursor as an alias, checking that the return value extension is .dbf, and then use file functions to read the file size. The cursor may be in-memory though (the reported 'filename' will have a .tmp extension, if I remember right) so an alternative would be to use RECCOUNT() (to get the number of rows) combined with AFIELDS() (to get the size of each row) to approximate the file size. (In-memory cursors can sometimes be forced to disk by including a NOFILTER clause in the generating query)

Comment: This is very helpful stuff.  We tried reccount()*afields() but afields can't tell you about the size of the memo fields.  I'm interested in forcing the table to disk, possibly.

Comment: The memos are stored in the file with the same name as the DBF, but it has an FPT extension. Memos are stored in blocks of XX characters determined when the file was created. So the actual memo size in characters is not accurately determined by this, but it gives you the bytes used on disk.

Answer (score 2):

RECSIZE() will return the length of an individual row in bytes -- that times the RECCOUNT() will give you the size.  All the elements already discussed are accurate.

With respect to memo fields, if you need to know how large THEY are, you might want to add a new integer column to your table structure for "MemoLength".  Then

replace all memoLength with len( alltrim( YourMemoField ))

Then, you can take the MemoLength to help determine your breakdown groups by taking this column size into consideration with the rest of you RECSIZE() * rows you want to extract out.

Additionally, you might want to run a query based on the primary key column of the table you can use as a link and do something like...

select YourPrimaryKey, len( alltrim( YourMemoField )) as MemoLength
  from YourTable
  into cursor SomeHoldingCursor readwrite

.. OR, select

into table MemSizeTable

Build an index on  the MemSizeTable and you can use a join on that to get more info.  This way, it won't distort your original record size, nor disrupt your original table structure, yet with a relation, you can still extract the elements you need.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fully functional based on a sample cursor and a bogus record...  The critical function is the DumpXML() routine and needs the alias of the file to be dumped, the size per file you want to cap it at (in "k" size), and the file name prefix you want the XMLs to be dumped as.  It will auto-generate a sequencing ex: MyXMLOutput1.xml, MyXMLOutput2.xml, MyXMLOutput3.xml, etc for however many instances it needs to go.  Took me about 15 minutes.

```
CREATE CURSOR SomeTest ;
    (   SomeField1      c(10),;
        AnotherField    i,;
        SomeNumber      N(8,2),;
        MemoFld         m,;
        SomeDateTime    t;
    )

INSERT INTO SomeTest VALUES ( "testchar10", 9403, 12345.78, "some memo value string", DATETIME() )


DumpXML( ALIAS(), 300, "MyXML" )


FUNCTION dumpXML
LPARAMETERS cAliasName, nSizeLimit, cNameOfXMLOutput
    IF NOT USED( cAliasName )
        RETURN ""
    ENDIF 

    */ Assume size limit in "k"
    nSizeLimit  = nSizeLimit * 1024

    SELECT ( cAliasName )

    */ Get a copy of the structure without disrupting original
    USE IN SELECT( "MySample" )  && pre-close in case left open from prior cycle
    SELECT * ;
        FROM ( cAliasName ) ;
        WHERE RECNO() = 1;
        INTO CURSOR MySample READWRITE

    SELECT MySample
    */ Populate each field with maximum capacities... typically
    */ critical for your char based fields
    AFIELDS( aActualStru )
    cMemoFields = ""
    lHasMemoFields = .f.
    FOR I = 1 TO FCOUNT()
        cFieldName = FIELD(I)
        DO CASE 
        CASE aActualStru[i,2] = "C"
            replace &cFieldName WITH REPLICATE( "X", aActualStru[i,3] )

        CASE aActualStru[i,2] = "L"
            replace &cFieldName WITH .T.

        CASE aActualStru[i,2] = "D"
            replace &cFieldName WITH DATE()

        CASE aActualStru[i,2] = "T"
            replace &cFieldName WITH DATETIME()

        CASE aActualStru[i,2] = "M"
            */ Default memo as a single character to ensure
            */ closing field name </endoffield> included in XML
            replace &cFieldName WITH "X"

            */ if a MEMO field, add this element to a string 
            */ to be macro'd to detect its size... Each record
            */ can contain MORE than one memo field...
            */ Ex: + LEN( ALLTRIM( MemoFld ))
            lHasMemoFields = .T.
            cMemoFields = cMemoFields + " + len( ALLTRIM( " + cFieldName + " ))"

        CASE aActualStru[i,2] = "I"
            */ Integer, force to just 10 1's
            replace &cFieldName WITH 1111111111


        CASE aActualStru[i,2] = "N"
            */ Actual numeric and not an integer, double or float
            */ Allow for full length plus decimal positions
            NumValue = VAL( REPLICATE( "9", aActualStru[i,3] - aActualStru[i,4] - 1 );
                            + "." + REPLICATE( "9", aActualStru[i,4] ))
            replace &cFieldName WITH NumValue

        ENDCASE     
    ENDFOR 

    */ Strip leading " + " from the string in case multiple fields
    IF lHasMemoFields
        cMemoFields = SUBSTR( cMemoFields, 3 )
    ENDIF 

    cXML = ""
    LOCAL oXML as XMLAdapter

    oXML = CREATEOBJECT( "XMLAdapter" )
    oXML.AddTableSchema( "MySample" )
    oXML.ToXML( "cXML", "", .f. )

    */ Now, determine the size of the per record at its full length -- less memo        
    nSizeOfPerRecord = LEN( STREXTRACT( cXML, "<MySample>", "</MySample>", 1, 4 ))

    */ and the rest of the header per XML dump
    nSizeOfSchema = LEN( cXML ) - nSizeOfPerRecord


    */ Now, back to the production alias to be split
    SELECT( cAliasName )
    nNewSize = 0
    nXMLCycle = 0

    */ if we just started, or finished writing another block
    */ and need to generate a new group of XML dump reset size
    nNewSize = nSizeOfSchema

    */ Always blank out the temp cursor for each batch...
    SELECT MySample
    ZAP 

    SELECT ( cAliasName )
    SCAN 
        IF lHasMemoFields
            nAllMemoSizes = &cMemoFields
        ELSE 
            nAllMemoSizes = 0
        ENDIF 

        IF nNewSize + nSizeOfPerRecord + nAllMemoSizes > nSizeLimit
            */ The upcoming record will have exceeded capacity, finish XML
            */ with all records up to this point
            nXMLCycle = nXMLCycle + 1
            cNewFile = FULLPATH( cNameOfXMLOutput + ALLTRIM( STR( nXMLCycle )) + ".XML" )

            oXML = CREATEOBJECT( "XMLAdapter" )
            oXML.AddTableSchema( "MySample" )
            */ Generate the XML cycle of these qualified records...
            oXML.ToXML( cNewFile, "", .t. )

            */ restart for next pass of data
            nNewSize = nSizeOfSchema

            */ Always blank out the temp cursor for each batch...
            SELECT MySample
            ZAP 
        ENDIF 

        */ Add record to total size...
        nNewSize = nNewSize + nSizeOfPerRecord + nAllMemoSizes

        */ we have a record to be included in segment dump...
        */ scatter from the original table and gather into the temp
        SCATTER MEMO NAME oFromOriginal

        SELECT MySample
        APPEND BLANK
        GATHER MEMO NAME oFromOriginal

        */ back to original table driving the XML Dump process
        SELECT ( cAliasName )

    ENDSCAN 


    */ if the "MyTable" has records not yet flushed from limit, write that too
    IF RECCOUNT( "MySample" ) > 0
        */ The upcoming record will have exceeded capacity, finish XML
        */ with all records up to this point
        nXMLCycle = nXMLCycle + 1
        cNewFile = FULLPATH( cNameOfXMLOutput + ALLTRIM( STR( nXMLCycle )) + ".XML" )

        oXML = CREATEOBJECT( "XMLAdapter" )
        oXML.AddTableSchema( "MySample" )
        */ Generate the XML cycle of these qualified records...
        oXML.ToXML( cNewFile, "", .t. )
    ENDIF 

    */ Done with the "MySample" for cursor to XML analysis...
    USE IN SELECT( "MySample" )

ENDFUNC
```